# How to update underlying bound KO data after using jQuery to update selected value in <select> drop-down?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'm using jQuery to update the selected value of a data-bound select drop-down
    $(item).val(newVal)
however, the underlying bound KO data is not updating.  Is there a way to get the bound data to update as well?

The javascript code that is updating the selectedIndex doesn't have knowledge of the data model

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fiddle to show how to do it the correct way, how you are doing it (the broken way) and how to do it like you have asked (the wrong way :) ), and a way of making it work)

http://jsfiddle.net/Kohan/h4HLs/2/

## Js

```
function vm() {
    var items = ko.observableArray(
           ['initial', 'changedModel', 'changedBroken', 'changedHacked']);

    var selectedItem = ko.observable();

    function changeModel(){
        selectedItem("changedModel");
    }

    function changeDropdown(){
        $("#selectBox").prop('selectedIndex', 2);
    }

    function changeDropdownHack(){
        $("#selectBox").prop('selectedIndex', 3);
        $("#selectBox").change();
    }

    return {
        items: items,
        selectedItem: selectedItem,
        changeModel: changeModel,
        changeDropdown: changeDropdown,
        changeDropdownHack: changeDropdownHack
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

## html

```
<select id="selectBox" data-bind="options: items, value: selectedItem"></select>
<h2>Selected Value: </h2>
<div data-bind="text: selectedItem"></div>

<button data-bind="click: changeModel">change Model</button><br />
<button data-bind="click: changeDropdown">change Dropdown With Jquery (Broken)</button><br />
<button data-bind="click: changeDropdownHack">change Dropdown With Jquery + Hack</button><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be inserting additional value to your viewModel.
Check if your value array for dropdown is .observableArray
if it is call .valueHasMutated(), after update.
you can select your knockout context like this

```
var knockoutContect = ko.contextFor($('#yourDropDown'));
```

Comment: can you elaborate a little further? I don't want to use KO, I would like to use jQuery to update the <select> drop-down and subsequently trigger update of underlying bound-data

Comment: Sorry that's how knockout works, you have to think on how to do things to model and not DOM.

Comment: What about firing change event in jQuery? Would something along those lines work?

Comment: What is your reasoning for wanting to do it with jQuery? It would be very easy to get this to work the proper way using knockout.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some code?

KO viewmodel updates automatically if you use the `value` binding in addition to the `options` binding:

```
<select data-bind="options: myOptions, value: myValue"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like 4imble already said, it's better / easier to just use knockout for this. So instead of `$(item).val(newVal)` you'd get something like `viewModel.dropdownObservable(newVal)`.

If this isn't an option for you though, you could update the viewmodel on the change event of the select:

```
ko.applyBindings({
    value: ko.observable(1)
});

var $select = $('#select');

// update the ViewModel value on change
$select.change(function() {
    ko.contextFor(this).$data.value($select.val());
});

// change the value and trigger the change event
$select.val(2).trigger('change');
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sjroesink/P83kz/